# Getting java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly when trying to connect to Kafka from Openshift ROSA

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, openshift, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to migrate a Springboot project that is deployed in Openshift V3 to Openshift V4(ROSA). The issue is that the project has Kafka integration and its not working in ROSA. I get the below error

```
logger_name: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler
   message: Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void KafkaProducerService.send(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
   stack_trace: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:144)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1701)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1519)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:572)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:275)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:365)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getLatestVersion(RestService.java:774)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getLatestVersion(RestService.java:765)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:360)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.lookupLatestVersion(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:175)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.lookupLatestVersion(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:159)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:106)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:489)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1511)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

I checked the certificates in V3 and ROSA, they look the same to me. Any pointers as to how to fix this exception please.

Connection string used is :

```
kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: <name1>-kafka-broker-n1-test:9093,<name2>-kafka-broker-n2-test:9093,<name3>-kafka-broker-n3-test:9093
    properties:
      schema.registry.url: https://<name>-schema-registry-n1-test:8081
      auto.register.schemas: false
      use.latest.version: true
      basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
      basic.auth.user.info: ${username}:${password}
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="${username}" password="${password}";
```

Comment: Where does your schema registry server run? Does it need to allow your new instance (IP allowing / Firewall)? Did it have SSL setup? Are your certs expired? What connection string / client config are you using?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have updated the connection config in the question. I have created firewall rules, but let me get some help to check if traffic is allowed, same for SSL and certificates. Thank you..

Comment: You should use quotes and brackets for property keys. But since you're getting a TLS exception, seems to be a certificate problem, or you shouldn't use HTTPS prefix on the address https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka.additional-properties